Why is my tkinter window crashing when running in a different thread for use in a Jupyter Notebook?
I heard tkinter is not threadsave, but nevertheless I don't understand the behaviour of this code or how I should do it without using threads.
I'm currently developing a simple tkinter window which should be in general standalone, but for introducing new features (I'm doing data science) I want to be able to run the window from a Jupyter Notebook. Assume I have the following simple GUI code:
class MyProg1:
    def GUI(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Glutamte Image ROI Detector")
        root.mainloop()

class MyProg2:
    def GUI(self):
        global root
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Glutamte Image ROI Detector")
        root.mainloop()

class MyProg3:
    def GUI(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Glutamte Image ROI Detector")
        self.root.mainloop()

gui1 = MyProg1()
gui2 = MyProg2()
gui3 = MyProg3()

From my prespective, the only difference between those three approaches is wether root is local, static or an class instance. In order to run the programm in background (I need to run code in other cells while the tkinter window is running), I tried
#Task1
task1 = threading.Thread(target=gui1.GUI)
task1.start()

#Task2
task2 = threading.Thread(target=gui2.GUI)
task2.start()

#Task3
task3 = threading.Thread(target=gui3.GUI)
task3.start()

While I can run the code for task1 as often as I like, running task2 or task3 a second time, the Kernel crashes with the message Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread.
What's even more crazy: If I call gui3.root as ONLY command in a single cell, forcing Jupyter to output <tkinter.Tk object .>, it actually works. But only if I run it in a single cell before starting a new thread. So somehow Jupyter Notebooks forces a change on the root object to not crash the Kernel.
Please help me, what am I missing here? How should I do run the window without using threads?

It worked for me without Jupyter Notebook.
